# ASYNC postbacks happening when SupportsPartialRendering is set to false

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

We're getting a confusing error on two of our pages in our ASP.NET application. Both pages originaly had  tags to reload the page every so often if a user sat on it for a while, but opted to remove those in favor of some AJAX flavoring. Specifically, we created timer controls on the page and wired the timer's tick event as a trigger for an update panel to reload a portion of the page. The page(s) also have scriptmanagers on them as we don't have one on the master page. This largely works great except we're getting a lot of these errors:

"The page is performing an async postback but the ScriptManager.SupportsPartialRendering property is set to false."

It is my understanding that if the .NET framework detects a browser doesn't support partial rendering it will set the ScriptManager.SupportsPartialRendering value to false and we're NOT overriding this in any fashion. Therefore, the pages shouldn't be by performing async postbacks if that value is false, but based on the error the postbacks are still happening and the page is throwing an exception.

Curiously, the user agent always seems to be GoogleBot or "Mozilla/4.0 (Windows 98; US) Opera 10.00 [en]".

I'd apperciate some insight. We've toyed with the idea of forcing the SupportsPartialRendering to true, but that doesn't explain why ASYNC postbacks are even occuring if the .NET framework is setting this to false based on the the browser caps.

Comment: Did you make any progress with this in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding this, too. It appears that newer browsers will also cause this exception. The items that I've found so far -- though I've not resolved my own scenario -- are as follows:

1. [Ensure the `<xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy" />` is not set to Legacy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343063%28d=lightweight,v=VS.90%29.aspx#CommunityContent)
2. [Potentially by removing Hidden fields](http://schupka.blogspot.com/2007/08/webtest-recorded-using-fiddler-fails.html)

You can disable partial rendering entirely by [setting `ScriptManager.EnablePartialRendering` to false](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386573.aspx). This will force an update panel to reload the entire contents of the panel at once.

Answer (score 0):

I find `SupportsPartialRendering` confusing as well because of the name and because it is doing two things.

1. It acts as a flag to determine if the browser supports partial-page rendering.  As a flag, it won't actually prevent asynchronous postbacks, that's why you get the error still.
2. You can use it as an override. You can allow asynchronous postbacks regardless of what the browser is, but you can't prevent it with this property.

Cheers.